# Pandas resample and interpolate function too slow

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a use case where I resample a small data frame created from a list of 10 json objects. There are 10 rows 50 columns in dataframe with 20% missing fields. After resampling I interpolate the dataframe column by column as I am to chose user defined interpolation method. The code for doing this as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(packets_dict)
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df = df.resample('60S').first()
for column in columns_rule:
    if column in df.columns:
        # replace value by null if it is out of given min and max values.
        if 'max_value' in columns_rule[column].keys():
            df[column] = df[column].where(df[column] < columns_rule['column']['max_value'])
        if 'min_value' in columns_rule[column].keys():
            df[column] = df[column].where(df[column] > column_rule[column]['min_value'])
        df[column] = df[column].interpolate(method=linear, limit=3)
```

I need to run this code on streaming data coming at high rate. But this code is taking too long to execute. I have done the profiling of this code which show the following results by running this code 990 times.

**resample** takes 137.347 seconds and called 990 times, 138.79 ms for one function call.

**where** 75.272 takes seconds and called 87120 times, 0.864 ms for one function call.

**interpolate** takes 21.928 seconds and called 43560 times, 0.503 ms for one function call.

Rest of the code is pretty fast and does not take much time. 
The total time taken by these functions to complete 990 iterations is 234.5 seconds that is almost 4 minutes which is much higher than our required rate. I need to optimize this code to reduce time by 20x to 30x. Is there any way I can optimize these pandas function or may be I am doing something wrong while using these function.

I am using Pandas 0.23.0 with python3.

I have searched for it but could not find any solution. Please help me out with your comments and suggestions.

Here is a sample data if someone wants to try:
Its not the actual data as it can't be shared but the data I am providing is very much in terms of number of floats, integers and strings moreover in terms of number of columns and rows. Moreover for string columns I use ffill or bfill not the interpolate function.

```js
packets_dict = [
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:05:40",'field1':12.4,'field2':'aab','field3':1234,'field4':12.4,'field5':'aab','field6':1234,'field7':12.4,'field8':'aab','field9':1234,'field10':12.4,'field11':'aab','field12':1234,'field13':12.4,'field14':'aab','field15':1234,'field16':12.4,'field17':'aab','field18':1234,'field19':12.4,'field20':'aab','field21':1234,'field22':12.4,'field23':'aab','field24':1234,'field25':12.4,'field26':'aab','field27':1234,'field28':12.4,'field29':'aab','field30':1234,'field31':12.4,'field32':'aab','field33':1234,'field34':12.4,'field35':'aab','field36':1234,'field37':12.4,'field38':'aab','field39':1234,'field40':12.4,'field41':'aab','field42':1234,'field43':12.4,'field44':'aab','field45':1234,'field46':12.4,'field47':'aab','field48':1234,'field49':12.4},
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:06:41",'field10':12.4,'field11':'aab','field12':1234,'field13':12.4,'field14':'aab','field15':1234,'field16':12.4,'field17':'aab','field18':1234,'field19':12.4,'field20':'aab','field21':1234,'field22':12.4,'field23':'aab','field24':1234,'field25':12.4,'field26':'aab','field27':1234,'field28':12.4,'field29':'aab','field30':1234,'field31':12.4,'field32':'aab','field33':1234,'field34':12.4,'field35':'aab','field36':1234,'field37':12.4,'field38':'aab','field39':1234,'field40':12.4,'field41':'aab','field42':1234,'field43':12.4,'field44':'aab','field45':1234,'field46':12.4,'field47':'aab','field48':1234,'field49':12.4},
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:07:42",'field1':12.4,'field2':'aab','field3':1234,'field4':12.4,'field5':'aab','field6':1234,'field7':12.4,'field8':'aab','field9':1234,'field10':12.4,'field11':'aab','field12':1234,'field13':12.4,'field14':'aab','field15':1234,'field16':12.4,'field17':'aab','field18':1234,'field19':12.4,'field20':'aab','field21':1234,'field22':12.4,'field23':'aab','field24':1234,'field25':12.4,'field26':'aab','field27':1234,'field28':12.4,'field29':'aab','field30':1234,'field31':12.4,'field32':'aab','field33':1234,'field34':12.4,'field35':'aab','field36':1234,'field37':12.4,'field38':'aab','field39':1234,'field40':12.4,'field41':'aab','field42':1234,'field43':12.4,'field44':'aab','field45':1234,'field46':12.4,'field47':'aab','field48':1234,'field49':12.4},
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:08:44",'field1':12.4,'field2':'aab','field3':1234,'field4':12.4,'field5':'aab','field6':1234,'field7':12.4,'field8':'aab','field21':1234,'field22':12.4,'field23':'aab','field24':1234,'field25':12.4,'field26':'aab','field27':1234,'field28':12.4,'field29':'aab','field30':1234,'field31':12.4,'field32':'aab','field33':1234,'field34':12.4,'field35':'aab','field36':1234,'field37':12.4,'field38':'aab','field39':1234,'field40':12.4,'field41':'aab','field42':1234,'field43':12.4,'field44':'aab','field45':1234,'field46':12.4,'field47':'aab','field48':1234,'field49':12.4},
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:09:46",'field1':12.4,'field2':'aab','field3':1234,'field4':12.4,'field5':'aab','field6':1234,'field7':12.4,'field8':'aab','field9':1234,'field10':12.4,'field11':'aab','field12':1234,'field13':12.4,'field14':'aab','field15':1234,'field16':12.4,'field17':'aab','field18':1234,'field25':12.4,'field26':'aab','field27':1234,'field28':12.4,'field29':'aab','field30':1234,'field31':12.4,'field32':'aab','field33':1234,'field34':12.4,'field35':'aab','field36':1234,'field37':12.4,'field38':'aab','field39':1234,'field40':12.4,'field41':'aab','field42':1234,'field43':12.4,'field44':'aab','field45':1234,'field46':12.4,'field47':'aab','field48':1234,'field49':12.4},
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:10:49",'field1':12.4,'field2':'aab','field3':1234,'field4':12.4,'field5':'aab','field6':1234,'field7':12.4,'field8':'aab','field9':1234,'field10':12.4,'field11':'aab','field12':1234,'field13':12.4,'field14':'aab','field15':1234,'field16':12.4,'field17':'aab','field18':1234,'field19':12.4,'field20':'aab','field21':1234,'field22':12.4,'field23':'aab','field24':1234,'field25':12.4,'field26':'aab','field27':1234,'field28':12.4,'field41':'aab','field42':1234,'field43':12.4,'field44':'aab','field45':1234,'field46':12.4,'field47':'aab','field48':1234,'field49':12.4},
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:11:50",'field1':12.4,'field2':'aab','field3':1234,'field4':12.4,'field5':'aab','field6':1234,'field7':12.4,'field8':'aab','field9':1234,'field10':12.4,'field11':'aab','field12':1234,'field13':12.4,'field14':'aab','field15':1234,'field16':12.4,'field17':'aab','field18':1234,'field19':12.4,'field20':'aab','field21':1234,'field22':12.4,'field23':'aab','field24':1234,'field25':12.4,'field26':'aab','field27':1234,'field28':12.4,'field29':'aab','field30':1234,'field31':12.4,'field32':'aab','field33':1234,'field34':12.4,'field35':'aab','field36':1234,'field37':12.4,'field48':1234,'field49':12.4},
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:12:54",'field1':12.4,'field2':'aab','field3':1234,'field4':12.4,'field5':'aab','field6':1234,'field7':12.4,'field8':'aab','field9':1234,'field10':12.4,'field11':'aab','field12':1234,'field13':12.4,'field14':'aab','field15':1234,'field16':12.4,'field17':'aab','field18':1234,'field19':12.4,'field20':'aab','field21':1234,'field22':12.4,'field23':'aab','field24':1234,'field25':12.4,'field26':'aab','field27':1234,'field28':12.4,'field38':'aab','field39':1234,'field40':12.4,'field41':'aab','field42':1234,'field43':12.4,'field44':'aab','field45':1234,'field46':12.4,'field47':'aab','field48':1234,'field49':12.4},
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:15:55",'field1':12.4,'field2':'aab','field3':1234,'field4':12.4,'field5':'aab','field6':1234,'field7':12.4,'field8':'aab','field9':1234,'field10':12.4,'field11':'aab','field12':1234,'field13':12.4,'field14':'aab','field15':1234,'field16':12.4,'field17':'aab','field18':1234,'field19':12.4,'field20':'aab','field21':1234,'field22':12.4,'field23':'aab','field24':1234,'field25':12.4,'field26':'aab','field27':1234,'field28':12.4,'field29':'aab','field30':1234,'field31':12.4,'field32':'aab','field33':1234,'field34':12.4,'field35':'aab','field36':1234,'field37':12.4,'field38':'aab','field39':1234,'field40':12.4,'field41':'aab','field42':1234,'field43':12.4,'field44':'aab','field45':1234,'field46':12.4,'field47':'aab','field48':1234,'field49':12.4},
{'datetime':"2018-08-01 22:16:01",'field1':12.4,'field2':'aab','field3':1234,'field4':12.4,'field5':'aab','field6':1234,'field7':12.4,'field8':'aab','field28':12.4,'field29':'aab','field30':1234,'field31':12.4,'field32':'aab','field33':1234,'field34':12.4,'field35':'aab','field36':1234,'field37':12.4,'field38':'aab','field39':1234,'field40':12.4,'field41':'aab','field42':1234,'field43':12.4,'field44':'aab','field45':1234,'field46':12.4,'field47':'aab','field48':1234,'field49':12.4}
]

columns_rule = {
'field1':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field3':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field4':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field6':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field7':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field9':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field10':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field12':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field13':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field15':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field16':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field18':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field19':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field21':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field22':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field24':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field25':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field26':'aab',
'field27':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field28':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field30':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field31':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field33':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field34':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field36':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field37':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field39':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field40':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field42':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field43':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field45':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field46':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field48':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
},
'field49':{
    'max_value':999,
    'min_value':0
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: @jezrael 
I have added the sample data which I am using for creating the dataframe in first line of code.

Comment: Thank you, is possible add sample of `columns_rule` ?

Comment: Added colums_rule too in the question. Please do let me know of your suggestions that I can perform on my data and share the results with you. Thanks for your interest in my question.

Comment: I think 20-30 times faster code is really more, maybe some 5 times is possible (depends of data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is extract values of dict in loop and then working with `DataFrame` of all matched columns and instaed `resample` is used [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) with `groupby`:

```
df = df.set_index('datetime').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60S')).first()

dmin, dmax = {}, {}
cmin, cmax = [],[]
for column in columns_rule:
    if column in df.columns:
        if 'max_value' in columns_rule[column]:
            dmax[column] = columns_rule[column]['max_value']
            cmax.append(column)
        if 'min_value' in columns_rule[column]:
            dmin[column] = columns_rule[column]['min_value']
            cmin.append(column)

m1 = df[cmax].lt(pd.Series(dmax))
m2 = df[cmin].gt(pd.Series(dmin))

cols = np.union1d(cmin, cmax)
df[cmax] = np.where(m1, df[cmax], np.nan)
df[cmin] = np.where(m2, df[cmin], np.nan)
df[cols] = df[cols].interpolate(method='linear', limit=3)
```

Comment: Thanks, It solve the problem, but I made it faster by removing outliers in python. Thanks for your solution, surely it improves time by 3 to 4 times. Thankyou so much for your help @jezrael